# Congestion and traffic

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

I have seen somewhere while studying TCP , that if there is traffic in the networks, then it is not necessary that congestion is also there? What is the  difference between Congestion and Traffic in computer networks?

Answer (score 0):

Just like cars on roads, congestion is *too much* traffic.

You can be said to have traffic when you're transferring your five-line shell script to another machine.

Congestion, on the other hand, may be what happens in the immediate hours after the latest Game Of Thrones episode is released on the torrent net :-)

TCP uses various methods to try and avoid congestion, such as gradually ramping up throughput in a session and continuously adjusting it as problems occur and disappear.